# Facebook (web) dialog started immediately dismissing on iOS6/SDK3.1|3.2

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I had some code to post to a friend's facebook wall that upon the deprecation of this via Open Graph I changed to use the deprecated headers and Facebook dialog to include the user in the posting. That has been working for weeks, but seems to have stopped working (worked fine Tuesday, failed Wednesday) in production application (i.e. no code change or re-build.)

I've spent hours trying all sort of things (running on main thread, asserting sessions are live, re-writting to SDK 3.2, uninstalling app/re-installing, completely changing the dialog type and post contents) to restore the ability but whatever I do the dialog immediately dismisses. [Note: There are no developer alerts on our app, and I believe that none of the app settings have changed.]

Here is the code. The facebookManager "performConnectedAction" is from the Facebook sample to ensure an active session (and I assert it w/o problem.) :

```
NSMutableDictionary *wallPost = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

  // Content populating not show (and I've tried various simplifications)

// Who to...
[wallPost setObject:_selectedUser.id forKey:kFB_FIELD_TO];

[facebookManager performConnectedAction:^{
    FBSession *facebookSession = facebookManager.facebookSession;
    Assert( facebookSession.isOpen, @"Need an open Facebook session.");

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:facebookSession parameters:wallPost handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL,NSError *error) {
        if ( !!error ) {
            [self logEventWithFormat:@"Failed to invite on Facebook [%@]", error];
        }
    }];
}];
```

Basically ... not only does the dialog flash up/down, but no callback is given (no error or result provided.) All other parts of the Facebook application continue to operate (our graph calls, our Facebook Friends dialog, and so on.)

I'd appreciate any thoughts on ways to investigate this further. I have filed a bug report:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165456656937602?browse=search_5130e2d7663dd6543665811

Comment: I tried to find why it does not work. You can read what I found there: [Bug > Facebook dialog stopped appearing (and no error callback invoked)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165456656937602?browse=search_5130e2d7663dd6543665811)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by delaying the method call like this. My method is `fbWallPost`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fbWallPost) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: Looking promising, thank you! Will do more testing and mark as correct (holding my nose to whatever Facebook SDK issues causes this to fail) once I've tested on a few more devices. Thanks for posting.